# Windows service stops receiving http requests

Tags: .net, windows, server, service

I have developed the following Windows service

**Clase Program**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebSocketService
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Punto de entrada principal para la aplicación.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new Service1()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

            /*Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());*/
        }
    }
}
```

**Clase Service1**

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;


namespace WebSocketService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            WebSocketService ws = new WebSocketService();
            ws.StartServer();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            WebSocketService ws = new WebSocketService();
            ws.StopServer();
        }

        
    }
}
```

**Clase WebSocketService**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using LocalEntity;
namespace WebSocketService
{
    public class WebSocketService
    {
        private HttpListener httpListener;
        private ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebSocket> connectedClients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebSocket>();
        private static WebSocketService webSocketService;
        public WebSocketService()
        {
            webSocketService = this;
        }

        public void StartServer()
        {
            try
            {
                httpListener = new HttpListener();
                httpListener.Prefixes.Add($"http://172.20.20.131:9292/v1/ws/suscribe/user/");
                httpListener.Prefixes.Add($"http://172.20.20.131:9292/v1/ws/publish/user/");

                httpListener.Start();
                LogController.WriteLog("WebSocket server started");
                ListenForClients();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogController.WriteLog($"Error starting server 172.20.20.131:9292: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private async void ListenForClients()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var context = await httpListener.GetContextAsync();
                    if (context.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
                    {
                        HandleWebSocketRequest(context);
                        LogController.WriteLog("New websocket server conection");
                    }
                    else if (context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/v1/ws/publish/user/")
                    {
                        HandleApiRequest(context);
                        LogController.WriteLog("New request http Api");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogController.WriteLog($"Error accepting WebSocket connection or handling API request: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
        }

        private async void HandleApiRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST" && context.Request.HasEntityBody)
                {
                    using (var body = context.Request.InputStream)
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[context.Request.ContentLength64];
                        await body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        string requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                        string messageToSend = requestBody;
                        webSocketService.BroadcastMessage(messageToSend);
                        string responseData = "Solicitud procesada con éxito";
                        byte[] responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseData);
                        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
                        context.Response.Close();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed;
                    context.Response.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogController.WriteLog(ex.Message);
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                context.Response.Close();
            }
        }

        public void BroadcastMessage(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var clientWebSocket in connectedClients.Values)
                {
                    if (clientWebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                    {
                        var responseBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                        clientWebSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(responseBuffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogController.WriteLog(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private async void HandleWebSocketRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                var webSocketContext = await context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null);
                var webSocket = webSocketContext.WebSocket;
                var clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                connectedClients.TryAdd(clientId, webSocket);

                var buffer = new byte[1024];

                while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

                        if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
                        {
                            var receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
                            LogController.WriteLog($"Received message from {clientId}: {receivedMessage}");
                            foreach (var clientWebSocket in connectedClients.Values)
                            {
                                if (clientWebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                                {
                                    var responseBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{clientId}: {receivedMessage}");
                                    await clientWebSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(responseBuffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                        {
                            connectedClients.TryRemove(clientId, out _);
                            await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Closed by server", CancellationToken.None);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (WebSocketException)
                    {
                        LogController.WriteLog("El cliente cerró la conexión abruptamente");
                        connectedClients.TryRemove(clientId, out _);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogController.WriteLog(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void StopServer()
        {
            httpListener?.Stop();
            LogController.WriteLog("WebSocket server stopped");
        }
        public class DataApi
        {
            public string Name { set; get; }
            public string Cod_Sap { set; get; }
        }
    }
}
```

The service listens to http requests and according to the url of the request it takes it as a connection to the WS or a request

The service works correctly on my Windows 10 machine but when I install it on a Windows Server 2019 server it stops receiving http requests when the user logs out, which is strange since if I log out of my Windows 10 the service continues listening normally.

It should be noted that I am not getting any errors in Windows Event Viewer or anywhere, the service stops listening when the user logs out and listens again when the user logs in again

**Service Details**
.Net framework 4.8
account configuration of type system application
Installed for all users